# How do you calculate the reddening corrections for photometry?

Tags: observational-astronomy, photometry

I have photometric data from Gaia for a star and am trying to de-redden the colors. I need to find the reddening corrections for the photometry. I have photometry for G, BP, and RP.

To start I am using the equation E(BP-RP)=(BP-RP)-(BP-RP)_0. I have values for E(BP-RP) and (BP-RP) and have solved for (BP-RP)_0. (ex.: E(BP-RP)=0.5, (BP-RP)=1.1 and so using the equation (BP-RP)_0=0.6)

I am confused on what to do next with the (BP-RP)_0 value to calculate the de-reddened colors. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: $(B_p -R_p)_0$ denotes a de-reddened colour. You need to rewrite your question to more clearly state your problem.